# Unexpected behaviour (bug?) with unicode-math in italic in TexLive 2016

Tags: math-mode, fontspec, unicode-math, opentype, boldmath

I recently updated to TexLive 2016 (specifically MacTex 2016) from TexLive 2015 and, without changing any source code, the output of a document changed with XeLaTeX. Specifically, bold math italic became bold math (not italic) and some uppercase bold math italic fonts became blank spaces. I am using

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO, sans-style=italic}
```

and the problem arises with both minion math and lucida OTF math fonts (possibly others, these are the only ones I tried) when using `\mathbf{u = \Omega}`. I can provide more details - a full MWE if needed - but I wondered first if this was a known issue? Or perhaps my way of calling the routines is deprecated.
 Thanks!

Comment: I think `unicode-math` underwent a big change a little while ago that changed a lot of how different font styles are applied/used. You could have a look at the manual for the latest version of `unicode-math`, and see if any of what you're doing conflicts with what is described there.

Comment: I think http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/reconciling-unicode-math-with-latex2e-mathematics/ is where I heard of it by the way.

Comment: The unicode-math manual (the one that pops up with `texdoc unicode-math`) looks to be the same as before. It is dated June 2014 and has the same calling parameters.

Comment: Add `\listfiles` to your file (before `\documentclass`) and check the list of packages that are added to the end of the `.log` file to see which version is actually used. In my TL2016 I have v0.8c of `unicode-math` dated September 2015.

Comment: Sorry, I meant September 2015 in my previous comment. However, the calling method seems to be the same with the new version, and in particular `\unimathsetup{math-style=ISO, bold-style=ISO}` still appears to be supported. I will look more closely though to see if anything else has changed, thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: I didn't mean the package loading etc., but the actual use of `\mathbf` and similar. There were some new macros introduced, e.g. `\symbf`. See the video I linked to and the manual (I'm no expert, so I don't know/remember any details.)

Comment: That helps, thanks. It looks like there are some backward incompatibilities in the new version along those lines.